# Perform calculations on dataframe column based on index value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, iteration

I have to monthly normalize values of one dataframe column `Allocation`.

```
data=
                     Allocation  Temperature  Precipitation  Radiation
Date_From                                                             
2018-11-01 00:00:00    0.001905         9.55            0.0        0.0
2018-11-01 00:15:00    0.001794         9.55            0.0        0.0
2018-11-01 00:30:00    0.001700         9.55            0.0        0.0
2018-11-01 00:45:00    0.001607         9.55            0.0        0.0
```

This means, if we have 2018-11, divide `Allocation` by 11.116, while in 2018-12, divide `Allocation` by 2473.65, and so on... (These values come from a list `Volume`, where `Volume[0]` corresponds to 2018-11 untill `Volume[7]` corresponds to 2019-06).

`Date_From` is a index and a timestamp.

```
data_normalized=
                     Allocation  Temperature  Precipitation  Radiation
Date_From                                                             
2018-11-01 00:00:00    0.000171         9.55            0.0        0.0
2018-11-01 00:15:00    0.000097         9.55            0.0        0.0
...
```

My approach was the use of itertuples:

```
for row in data.itertuples(index=True,name='index'):
    if row.index =='2018-11':
        data['Allocation']/Volume[0]
```

Here, the if statement is never true...

Another approach was 
`if ((row.index >='2018-11-01 00:00:00') & (row.index<='2018-11-31 23:45:00')):`
 
However, here I get the error `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'str'`

Can I solve my problem with this approach or should I use a different approach? I am happy about any help

Cheers!

Comment: Do you mind to share your expected output? It's not that clear to me what do you want to achieve. You might read about [mcve](/help/mcve) too.

Comment: In particular it's not clear what `Volume` is.

Comment: I edited the question. Volume is a list

Comment: do you know already that `Volume` as at least the same number of elements for the different months?

Comment: Yes, I consider 8 months and I have 8 elements in `Volume`

Comment: How can we guess whether the index is a string or a Timestamp? How can we guess what month correspond to what index in the Volume list? What cannot you understand in [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can put your list `Volume` in a dataframe where the date (or index) is the first day of every month.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 16
date = pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', periods=N, freq="15d")
df = pd.DataFrame({"date":date, "Allocation":np.random.randn(N)})

# A dataframe where at every month associate a volume
df_vol = pd.DataFrame({"month":pd.date_range(start="2018-01-01", periods=8, freq="MS"),
                       "Volume": np.arange(8)+1})

# convert every date with the beginning of the month
df["month"] = df["date"].astype("datetime64[M]")

# merge
df1 = pd.merge(df,df_vol, on="month", how="left")

# divide allocation by Volume. 
# Now it's vectorial as to every date we merged the right volume.
df1["norm"] = df1["Allocation"]/df1["Volume"]
```

Comment: @jonasa in your case you have to convert `Date_From` to `datatime` you can use `df["Date_From"]=df["Date_From"].astype("M8[us]")`